IK Mechanism Snaps Back To Normal Pole Angle After Moving A Bone After Mirroring Pose
Whenever I mirror a pose when animating, the pole angles on the legs flip unless I move one of the bones, then the IK mechanism snaps back to the normal pole angle.  I know the problem is only a click and drag away from ceasing, but it's definitely disorienting when I'm trying to animate.  Is there a way I can stop this from happening?
